# Observable emits all values on subcribe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, reactivex

I've got some code that looks like this (this is an excerpt of a much larger project):

```
this.oldMessagesSubject = new Subject<Message[]>();
this.oldMessages = this.oldMessagesSubject.asObservable();

getOldMessages(): Observable<Message[]> {
    this.chatHub.server.getMessages();
    return this.oldMessages;
}
```

I then subscribe to it like this:

```
this.chatService.getOldMessages()
    .subscribe(res => this.messages = res);
```

I'm not very experienced with ReactiveX, but when I subscribe to the observable returned by getOldMessages(), it iterates through each of the values that it has received since the app started. So if I get the old messages for 'chat 1' that works fine. But if I then navigate to a different page and get the old messages for 'chat 2' the observable emits the messages for 'chat 1' and then the messages for 'chat 2'.

I have a feeling I'm using the Observables in the wrong way and I'd really appreciate any help.

EDIT:
This is where `next` is called:

```
this.chatHub.client.showMessages = (messages: Message[]) => this.oldMessagesSubject.next(messages);
```

`getMessages` is an RPC to the server. Here is the relevant method on the server (C#):

```
public Task GetMessages()
        {
            try
            {
                // Get the current user
                var user = repo.GetUser(Context.User.Identity.Name);
                // Associate the current user with a connection
                var connection = chatContext.Find(x => x.UserId == user.UserId);

                if (connection != null)
                {
                    // Get all the messages in the user's chat (encrypted)
                    List<EncryptedMessage> encryptedMessages = repo.GetMessages(connection.ChatId);
                    List<Message> messages = new List<Message>();
                    // Get the decrpytion key
                    byte[] key = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["secret"]).Take(16).ToArray();

                    // Decrypt the messages
                    foreach (var encryptedMessage in encryptedMessages)
                    {
                        Message message = new Message();
                        message.Id = encryptedMessage.Id;
                        message.GroupId = encryptedMessage.GroupId;
                        message.Owner = encryptedMessage.Owner;
                        message.Sent = encryptedMessage.Sent;
                        message.Body = cryptoProvider.DecryptMessage(encryptedMessage.Body, key);

                        messages.Add(message);
                    }

                    // Return the messages to the client
                    return Clients.Caller.ShowMessages(messages);
                }

                return Clients.Caller.LoginError();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Clients.Caller.Exception(ex);
            }
        }
```

When I'm back at my workstation, I'll debug and check that the problem isn't server side. I should be able to tell if `next` is being called multiple times on each subscription.

Comment: Are you sure there is no `ReplaySubject` mixed into somewhere in your app? How is `this.chatHub.server.getMessages();` involved? What does it do/change/...?

Comment: where do you call the Subject's `next` method?

Comment: @chrigu I'm using SignalR for communication with the server. getMessages is an RPC to the server, I'll include the code for that in the post. I'll also put the place where next is called in the post.